# Set image for more button in tab bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have 6 options on my tab bar. So naturally after 4 options, the more button is shown. The more button is indicated by 3 dots. But I want to change the 3 dots (default) image of the more button and instead replace it with a different image.

How can I achieve that..?

Answer (score 1):

You may try Using below code When you have more than five items in tabbar, you may try putting this code in your initialViewController of tabbar.

```
self.tabBarController?.moreNavigationController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "title", image: image, selectedImage: selectedImage)
```

Comment: check updated one. its Working like a charm and its a valid way.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @Abu Ul Hassan... I did try it just now...But it's not working.

Comment: you maybe adding it in initial controller , But you need to put in viewDidLoad of tabbar's initial controller i have tested it :)